# I wrote a function in php but somehow it fails

Tags: php

```
function gp_barrier_check($amount) {
    $return = 1;

    if ($amount == 11  OR $amount == 12  OR $amount == 18  OR $amount == 35  OR
        $amount == 58  OR $amount == 75  OR $amount == 81  OR $amount == 114 OR
        $amount == 115 OR $amount == 288 OR $amount == 317 OR $amount == 344 OR 
        $amount == 403 OR $amount == 574 OR $amount == 804 OR $amount == 1093)
    {
        $return = 0;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

It works fine but it fails once when send 18. I don't know why function failed.

Comment: 1) Please define `fails` (error, unexpected results, what's the output). 2) It's a really bad practice to have that huge condition.

Comment: Just use `if(in_array($amount, [11, 12, 18, ...]))`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..sorry for my wrong explanation...i meant it return 0 when i send 18 always but it sent 1 one time...can you suggest if any kind of testing tools i can use to find out when my code return wrong value

Comment: According to your condition if you send `18` it should return `0`. What does `but it sent one time...` mean?

Comment: @Pushkar This question would be closed as off-topic on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) as the user is asking about a scenario for which his code is broken, and code which does not work as intended is off-topic for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

Nathan's answer is fine but it's going to return true if the amount is found in the array, whereas the OP wants to return `0` in such a case. Thus:

```
function gp_barrier_check($amount) 
{
    return (int)!in_array((int)$amount, array(11,12,18,35,58,75,81,114,115,288,317,344,403,574,804,1093));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason your function shouldn't work providing it is used correctly however as users have pointed out in the comments section, the approach taken is less than ideal. My suggestion would be the following:

```
function gp_barrier_check( $amount ) {
    return (int) in_array( $amount, array( 11, 12, 18, ) );
}
```

I'm casting the return value as an integer to match your original question although it seems likely that you'll want a boolean in which case just remove `(int)`.

Comment: If comparing numbers, it's more efficient to use `in_array((int)$amount, array( 11, 12, 18 ), true);`